# Probability to win at least once in N toss-the-coin games

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

I play N times toss-the-coin game (try to guess the result of tossing a coin). The game is fair/unbiased, I have 0.5 probability to win in each game.

In N games I cannot sum probabilities (summation of probabilities rule) because `1/2 + 1/2 = 1` which is a stupid result (100% probability to win at least once in 2 games).

What is the correct way to calculate probability?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sum probilities because $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ . That is, the probability of "$A$ or $B$" is the sum of the individual probabilities only if the events are disjoint (not the case here).

The event "winning at least one game" is the complement of "losing all games". Hence, calling $L_i$ the event "losing the game $i$", the desired probability is

$$1 - P(L_1 \cap L_2 \cap ... L_n)=1- \prod P(L_i) = 1- \prod(1-p_i)$$

where $p_i$ is the probability of winning game $i$. In this case we get $$1- \left(\frac12\right)^n$$

Comment: I cannot understand why the events are disjoint. Events "win game 1" and "lose game 1" cannot happen simultaneously at the same time, but the rule "subtract probability of events happening simultaneously" applies only to events that can happen  simultaneously. Could you help me to clarify my understanding of "events" and to what events exactly this rule is applied. I understand the rule itself (theoretically).

Comment: In my explanation, events $A$ $B$ are _not_ disjoint, because they are $A="$win game 1" and "$B=$"win game 2".  And they surely can happen both.